# Change textBox.Text from static method

Tags: c#, static, static-methods, invoke

I am running server/client communication.
Now i want to write something on the server `textBox` and show it on the client `textBox` so I am sending a message from the server to the client which takes it using a static method:

```
    static void Client_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        //Client only accepts text messages
        var message = e.Message as ScsTextMessage;
        if (message == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Now I just want to append the message to the client `textBox` from this static method. I guess that I will need some kind of `invoke` but I don't know how to do it, and I cant find anything useful on [Google](http://www.google.com).

Comment: Well *which* text box do you want to change? You're in a static method, so there's no context.

Comment: Ok, i have Client application and it has it's own tbox TextBox which is on Form called Client. So i want to change tbox text.

Comment: But logically, from the point of view of the method, there could be multiple forms - or none! Why is this a static method? (Is this on the form? There's a lot you haven't told us.)

Comment: Oh, i am sorry it don't have to be static, posting answer.

Comment: Yes as Martin pointed out, this will only work if your Client class has a static TextBox field (meaning there can only be one). Then you can update it from your static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke method

```
public void AppendText(string what, bool debug = false)
     {
         if (debug)
             return;
         if (this.InvokeRequired)
         {
             this.Invoke(
                 new MethodInvoker(
                 delegate() { AppendText(what); }));
         }
         else
         {
             DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
             tbox.AppendText(timestamp.ToLongTimeString() + "\t" + what + Environment.NewLine);
         }
     }
```

Message received method

```
 private void Client_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            //Client only accepts text messages
            var message = e.Message as ScsTextMessage;
            if (message == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            AppendText(message.Text, false);

            //Console.WriteLine("Server sent a message: " + message.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Program.cs

public static ProgramForm Form;

publi static void Main()
{
    // ...
    Application.Run(Form = new ProgramForm());
    // ...
}

public static void ChangeText(String message)
{
    Form.TextBox1.Text = message;
}

// ProgramForm.cs

private void Client_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message != null)
        Program.ChangeText(e.Message);
}
```